# Apache name-based virtual servers without DNS

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, configuration, virtualhost

I have Apache web server installed on local Windows 7 x64 machine. It has no global DNS name.

In default distribution it has virtual host configured in Apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file.

It has one directive

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

and multiple directives

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

with different

```
ServerName www.domain.tld
```

Different names are written in `hosts` file and all pointing to `127.0.0.1`.

Unfortunately, virtual hosts do not work. Only first `<VirtualHost>` tag seems to be active. Nothing said on `httpd.exe` starting and in `error.log`.

How to make virtual hosts working here?

**EDIT**

I see no reason why DNS can be required. `GET` request contains symbolic name of the site, so, the server has all information to distinguish which virtual host was called.

**EDIT 1**

I found that virtual hosts DO work (without DNS!). It is a problem with one specific host.

Comment: The reason that DNS is normally used is that that is what most web browsers USE to set the Host: header. HTTP/1.1 requires the right Host: header to talk to virtual hosted websites. That said, you are free to put anything you like into a local hosts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtualhosts are configured in the following file : extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Here is an example on how to configure a Virtual Host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@website.com
DocumentRoot "/var/sites/website"
<Directory "/var/sites/website">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny   
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ServerName www.website.com
#ServerAlias www1.website.com
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Remember to :

Configure your Normal and Aliasses names on your DNS manager, and remember to include this file on the httpd.conf main directives.

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: Sorry, what is DNS manager? I have no DNS name on a computer as I said.

Comment: After that, restart the server httpd -k restart

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what to do. All you said was already done at my computer except DNS.

Comment: Add the <virtualHost> tags as I mentioned on your httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file, and make it fit to your servers name (The same name you configure on the dns otherwise it wont work)

Comment: I have no DNS, as I said. I am controlling access with `hosts` file. See no reason why it can't work with `hosts`.

Comment: There is no reason, but it will only work with clients that HAVE hosts entries for your server. Most clients will not.

Comment: In that case, the ServerName, should comply with the DNS registered name of your site, and the thing is done.

Comment: can you post here, how it looks the hosts file ?